# Generate ACS url with express and passport-saml for Gsuite SSO

Tags: node.js, express, saml-2.0, google-workspace, passport-saml

I'm implementing a SAML based SSO with nodejs using express and passport-saml for GSuite. I'm able to configure the first part and get passport-saml to redirect me to the google login page. But I'm stuck regarding the ACS url and identity ID that gsuite ask me to finish the configuration. So when I log myself on the google login page I end up with a 503 from google. I think I kinda understand how SAML works but I working with it for the first time so I may be totally wrong.

After a lot of research I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897549/5370826) but I'm not sure that I understand it well. It says that I can use the same urls that I set up for the `path` and `callback` parameters for passport

Here is how my passport configuration look like:

```
 passport.use(                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  new SamlStrategy(                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      protocol: "https://",                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      path: "/auth/saml/callback",                                                                                                                                                                                    
      entryPoint: "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=XXXXXX",                                                                                                                                                               
      issuer: "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?idpid=XXXXXX",                                                                                                                                                                       
      cert: fs                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        .readFileSync("./cert.pem", "utf-8")                                                                                                                                                                                               
        .replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "")                                                                                                                                                                                        
        .replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "")                                                                                                                                                                                          
        .replace(/\n$/, "")                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    function(profile, done) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      done(null, {                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        email: profile.email,                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        name: profile.name                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
);
```

And here how my passport related routes are configured:

```
app.post(
  "/auth/saml/callback",
  passport.authenticate("saml", {
    failureRedirect: "/error",
    failureFlash: true
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/logged");
  }
);

app.get(
  "/login/saml",
  passport.authenticate("saml", {
    failureRedirect: "/login/saml"
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
);
```

`/login/saml` is a route that I use to dispatch which configuration I want to use with passport since I'm using `MultiSamlStrategy`, I didn't put it in the passport intentionally.

Can someone explain me what do I need to set for the ACS url and Entity ID in Gsuite ? I think understood that the ACS url must return an XML with my service information, but I can't understand how to generate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The  `entityID` identifies the SP (your app) to the IdP (GSuite). Generally the IdP uses the `entityID` to find the SP's SAML metadata. The Attribute Consumer Service (`ACS`) URL will be in the SP's metadata. This is how it should work. You generally cannot give an IdP an `ACS` and get the SAML `Response` back as it's a security hole. I haven't used the GSuite IdP but I presume you tell the configuration the `ACS` url?

From the [passport docs](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml), `entryPoint` is the login endpoint at the IdP. The IdP already knows its entityID so you shouldn't need it:

```
entryPoint: "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp
```

issuer is where your `entityID` goes:

```
issuer: "YOUR_ENTITYID"
```

according to your config, your ACS is:

```
"/auth/saml/callback"
```

so you'll need the route:

```
app.post('/auth/saml/callback',
  bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }),
  passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);
```

remembering that `issuer` is your `entityID`.

So to summarise:

> Can someone explain me what do I need to set for the ACS url and
>   Entity ID in Gsuite ?
>   ACS url is the fully qualified url to:

```
/auth/saml/callback
```

and `entityID` (`issuer`) is whatever you called it in your metadata. It's generally a `URI` such as:

```
https://your.app/saml/sp
```