# SAML/ADFS SSO on Sailsjs MVC using nodejs throwing error : TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Location"]

Tags: node.js, sails.js, single-sign-on, adfs, passport-saml

I am setting up SSO on my sailsjs application using ADFS and passport-saml, when I am trying to sign-in it throwing: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Location"]` in place of redirecting to our adfs(IDp)

I have tried two process one is `passport-saml`(reference - http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-saml/) and other one is `passport-wsdef-saml2`(reference - https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2) but getting same error with both the implementations.
I have been through this url - [SAML/ADFS node.js implementation guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901368/saml-adfs-node-js-implementation-guide?rq=1) but nothing found missing in the code.
I am putting my passport-saml implementaion code here.

```
passport.js - 
passport.use(new SamlStrategy({
    entryPoint: 'https://myadfs.com/adfs​/ls',
    issuer: 'app-identity',
    callbackUrl: 'https://my-app.com/login/callback',
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/sign.crt', 'utf-8'),
    authnContext: 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password',
  identifierFormat: null  
  },
  function(profile, done) {
    console.log("data : ", profile );
    var data = {
      email: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'],
      givenname: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname'],
      surname: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname']
    }
    done(null, data);
  }));

route.js -

'GET /signin': 'AuthController.dologin',
'post /login/callback': 'AuthController.callback',
'/logout': 'AuthController.logout',`

AuthController.js -
  `dologin: function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('saml', (req, res) => {
      res.redirect('/');
    })(req, res);
  },
  callback: [passport.authenticate('saml', {failureRedirect: '/',failureFlash: true}),  function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.user);
    if (!req.user) {
      throw Error('User not authenticated.');
    }
    res.redirect('/');
  }
  ],
  logout: function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/login');
  }

http.js - 
passportInit: require('passport').initialize(),
    passportSession: require('passport').session(),
    order: [
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'passportInit',
      'passportSession',
      'bodyParser',
      'compress',
      'poweredBy',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
    ],
```

Please help me out, I am stuck even couldn't able to find where is the problem actually.
As per tutorials and findings, nothing seems incorrect but still, it's not redirecting to the ADFS Identity provider server, and throwing the following error -

```
0|app  | TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Location"]
0|app  |     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:473:3)
0|app  |     at Strategy.strategy.redirect (app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:323:13)
0|app  |     at redirectIfSuccess (app/node_modules/passport-saml/lib/passport-saml/strategy.js:77:12)
0|app  |     at DeflateRaw.requestToUrlHelper [as cb] (app/node_modules/passport-saml/lib/passport-saml/saml.js:361:5)
0|app  |     at DeflateRaw.zlibBufferOnEnd (zlib.js:131:10)
0|app  |     at DeflateRaw.emit (events.js:203:15)
0|app  |     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
0|app  |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Please help me what to do, where could be the problemin the above code.

Thank you in advance.